# 24 Задание ЕГЭ Информатика . Python

Tags: python

Есть такое задание :
текстовом файле k7c-1.txt находится цепочка из символов латинского алфавита A, B, C, D, E. Найдите количество цепочек длины 3, удовлетворяющих следующим условиям:
•   1-й символ – один из символов B, C или D;
•   2-й символ – один из символов B, D, E, который не совпадает с первым;
•   3-й символ – один из символов B, C, E, который не совпадает со вторым.

Я написал для него программу на Питоне :

```
f=open("k7c-1.txt", 'r')
a=f.read()
total = 0
i=0
while i<(len(a)-2):
if (a[i]=='B' or a[i]=='C' or a[i]=='D') and (a[i+1]=='B' or a[i+1]=='D' or a[i+1]=='E')!=a[i] and (a[i+2]=='B' or a[i+2]=='C' or a[i+2]=='E')!=a[i+1]:
  total=total+3
        i=i+3
  else:
total = 0
 i=i+1
print(total)
```

У меня получился ответ "6", но я не знаю точный верный ответ. И скорее всего у меня ошибка в условии программы . Можете проверить это ?

Текстовый файл для задания:
EAACEEDABDDADDABDECBBCCEBECEDEABEDECCDBCCDECDEEABDADEBABDEDDEECECCDAAEDADDECEAADDBBCBBDBDAACDDBEEABDBDDAEEDEBACEBDEADDECBEEADAEACADEBEEDCDDBACCDBCEDECACDCDDCDCDAADDEECCABAEBCACECABBBCBDBCDACCCAEDCCABCDCCCDBDEECCCAEBEDDCCEDAEABABAEADDCCCDCBABADCACDDDBCDEDDCAAAAACAECEEEAABDDEECCBEDCEBDAEAECDADBBDADAADDAADCDCAECEEACCBBEEABDCABBBEEABDAAAECACDDDCAACCCABDDDECACCAAACCDBDEAADEECBDCBACACCDDDABDDACCCAACDCCECEAEDDBBCCDCBADABBBBCBBCAABBCACACADDCDADBECBACCADCCEDDDAABEDEEEDDDEBDEBDEDBDAADBEDAACBBEEEDBBDBBEEDDBCDBCBEBEEBAEACCCEACBBEDABCBDEBCADDBBCCDDCEAADAEEDBDBADBDDCDCAEEBBCCACAADCADBCABACBAAAEBCADDDDECBAAECDCBEEEDBCCAEBDBCCAAEDECCADCDABBDEAECDDEAACCEEBAEBDACDDECCDCDEBDACECBCCEDBACBEBDAABEDBDBCEACCECEAAEBCDCCAAEDEBBCBCEEBBEBCACBADECEAEECAEEABDEBADAEDCDBDCCBDBABEAEDDDAEDAEBBACEBBCBCACEBDAABACCDCEDDCBCADADCCBABECCDBEBEAACBEDAECBAAACDDABDDCDACDACDEBAACDEEEAAECCBDECBCEAEDBAABECEEBBDDADEEACDCACBDEBADDAEDCEDCBCACDEECBCCCADECADEEADECEDBBDBCEDEECBDEDEACDAADECCECBDBDABCBBEDCBCBDADBDAEBABEBCDDEDDEADDAAAECDEDDBDECEEEEAAACCBDBBCADDBBEECCBEDBCDCEABCDBDDEEBDEABDCBBDACDADABEACDEEBCDEEAACCAAEEACBDEAEEEABEBDBDEACDBDAABCACEADCDAAABBCEAECDDCDDBDCCAADCDEBDAACCEECCDDBEEBDEECBEBECDDBDDEEEACBCADBBACCBBCDEAABAEBBBADCDDDBCDBCBEDCDBBBDDCABAEDCAAEEADEBCCBBDADDEBBEBBCDAACDCBBBADCBCAAABBCEACCCECEDABABBACDACCCDADEAEABEABBCDCBCACCCEADDDEBBBEBEDDEDBBBEBAEECCDECEACBBDBDEEEECDADDBCCDBBDADEBECAAACDDACCEBCABCCDDECCACCABACAAADCACBABCEDADBABADCDEDCDEAAEBDCDCADDDEDEDCBDCBCDCDBCDEDCDEEAADDDDEBDDECEBABEEBDBBAADBCEEABDCACBBDAABCCCCBABEAECECABEAADAECDECDDAACABECADBDCBBEBDBDEDBEBCAEDAADDBAECABDEAAEEBBEDDEDDACBDEEEACEEBAECEDABABBCECEDBECDACDCAAEDDBEEADBAEACEBDBADEECCBAADCAEEBBECCBBABAAEADAEEADCABEBADDCCACBBCEDDBCAAECDCBAADDBCEAEEBCCDBCEBCCEECCCABEBEADECCDECCEADEBDCDBECACCBCDAAABABAADAAABBCEBACADDBDABDDDCCAEAEDCAAACDDDBEDCADBEBCBCEEDEABCABDACBDBADBEBDDCDEABEEDCCAAABEDADEDEBCAEEDEADBDEEECBEEADEDBCBBDABDDAEDCCDCBDACBDCABADBEBEEDDBBBECAEEDEECCEBCEDEABDCEEECCCEBBEDCCECAEDCBAADCEDAABDCAACDBCEEEACEEDCCEDBCEADECECEADDADEACAECEBEAECCCEBBDECCEAEECDCDEBBDABCBBEBCDDAADAAAEEDBBCABBCCAEBECCADBABCDBCACEEDCCBEDDBABBDBCCCCCCCDDEADDBECDAECECBCEEABCDDBBEBECEADEACDCBBEDCBCDCCADACCBBDCADCCAABDACDBDBBAABEACAADCADDABBEEDEEEBAACDAAEADCEAEEACCCCACDECDEAADACADEDECCDBBBADDBDBEDEBABBADDADCACCCBDADECEBBDBCEBEBCAABACBBAECDDAEAEDAEBAEAEAECDBEEBEEEDBCBCBDCDDECAEACECBDCCCEAEDDDCCECABEEBEAACCBEECBEDEECDDEDEEAEBADBCECDDCECADEBDEBBBDDAEBDDBABBCEBECEAECCDCEABDEDBDCCAACCCACABBDCCCAEBEADCBACCACDDEEACDDBDDBBEACEEEAAAAADEDACCDADCCAEAEBBEECEDEDDBCEADAECCBAEABCAEABCEBEEBCBECBCBCADBCBBACCABEDBDCBEBEDADEACACCABBBEABABDBCAEBBAEDEBABADECEABECCEDBEDBBADCACCAAEBABCDEAACEEAECCCCCAAEAACBCDAAEDDDAABADDAADDEADEDADEDECAEDECBBEECAADAEDDCADAEDDBAEBCEAABDBBDCACDADBBCBEEBECEBCACEEDDEECAEABEEDCCAEDAEBEBADCACEDDAEBABACEEBAADDAAECCDDECDAEEDDBAEBABCBEAECCAEBDEECCEDBEACEDBDDBDDBBECEBEBCCACBDAEDCEEABABCACEDCECACAEBCECEADDBDDACCDDBDDCAECDDADCAEEEAEDCECDABEDCDDABCBCDBCCCCEEAADEBEBBADDECEEDABBCECAECEADDBAABDADCAABDEADBBCAEEDECACBBBEBCCECBDDABDCADEAABCEABECAEEDBEEEDBDBAADDCCACCDEDECEEEEADEEAEAEBBCCDACEACCBBECEBABBACCBACDAAAABABEABDBBCEADEAACCCBEBAEDDACCCCCDCDDBAABEBDBABECEDAAECCDBEBEBCEDEADAECEDEECCCBDEDDDDBAECBEDDAABBAAACDABBCAAEABCBADDBECDCABBABCBBCBCBDEBAAAEDDACDABCDBCBADECABACABDDACDDEEBDEDEBCECEDCEAAADCADCACABBDDDAEBBEDDCDDDDDBBDCBBBDEEEAEBECCEECCABCBBCCCEDCBBCDACDCBEEABDCDDCDBEBEEBCCECEDDCECCCEDABCBDECBDEDEDADCAEBBCCBACBBADAABDBBBCBBECDABCBEBDBBBCEEDBDDEBDCCDBABEBEECACBBEACCEBECCDABEDEBCBBBBCBBAEBCDBEDDCDDBCEABACBCABDBDEDAEDDDECABDAECEEBBEEECBDBDEAACBCCCBBBCBAAEBBCEEEBDEDAAEDBBBCECCBABCBCBCCCBEABBEDCBCCBBDBCBEEEDBEEBCEDACECBCDCDBEEDECCADBABAADEAAACEECCCBDCDEBABECBDEBAEEECAAEBAADADBBBCDBDDDEAAEDDEEBDECDEEDBADAEBCCEDEBBDEEAAECDEDCBBCACBCACBDAACCDADACDEBCBCDEADECACCDBBCECEADCBAEDAEEACEDECBAEADEEBACAAEACBCBDEADDDCCDCBAECCBCDBBDBDCCBCCBEEADACDBCAEBEDADBDEEEBDCBBAAAEBBBEBDEADEDABDAACEDCCBADCBCDAAABEEBAAECBDDABBBEDECDDEEABACCEAAACCAEBCACDBAEAEECCDAAABADDDBDDCBCABBEEABBAABADCDBDCEEACEECDBEBEDCBACCCECBDACDEEAEEEBBEEBACCEDADAAAADECEEADBEEEACBDCDEBDCCCBBEDDBEDBEBEECDAADAEBAAECCBBBEBCEEEECCAEAEDEDCEECCCBAEDEAEEDADABEAEAEEEAADDBABADEADDACBAEDDEEABADCDAECBEBCEEAEDCDEDDABDCDEDEEBAEECDDCDDEEAEBDEECDACDCBBBAEDEACEBABDBEBCDCCCBBEDCABEDBCABECDEEDECCDCADBDDADDCCDCDCAACDCAEDBEBBBBEEAABAACCAACCBCDCBBAECDAADCCEEBCDCCAEEADBCDCBCAACEAEAABBEACCBBABDBBCDABBCCBCCDADBEDBEBDEDEEADBBCAAEDCDBEADADBBBBADBEADBBDBABACCDCDAACEABBDDACAEDCBCCEABBBBEEBCEBDBECCECAEBCDADEBCCBBAECCCEEEDADBEBAEAAAACBABACEAAEADECEBEDAECABAABAAEBABCBBCDDAAEDBEACBEDACBBEDCCDBEDBEEECBCEEDDEDBACCEBAECABDEDCABDBEEADBCBECCAACEBCEEDEECDBAECABDBEABDCBEECADEBECADDBCAEBDEBEACABBACEAADEABEBBDCEEEABEADCEBEEEDACBDEDBDBACAADDAECECCABAEEEABECBEEEDBEBECADDDEDCBDACCECAECEDDDCACBBBCCDEEDAAACEDAEDEBDCDACCABAEDEADBBDCADDDECBABDCCCEADCEBEACDAEABEAACEBEBDCBCCEBDEACDBCEDCBABBDBBEBDBCCEBDBBCBEDACBBBCBEBBCCAACDAEADBDBDDECDBDAADAEDEDACCCDCCAABDBBCEDACBCCCBDECACCCBABDCCCCEEDEDCACECDDADBEDCEECCAACBAEDAEEBCDDABEDEBECEAEEBEAECDEEAEBAAADEDCDCCDACECDDAECECCBADACEDDAACBADBBECCEECECECCBCEDEBDEDEECDAEBCEEAACEBADACDDCECDACBAADCDECBADEACDCBADEECDDBECCEBAECBEACAEBEDBDDCCBCACEACBBECEACBBBEDEAEAACCDEBEDECCDBECEEDCDBEEABCCBCDACBBDDEDEBEACADDBAEADCBCEBECDBABDAACBCBEDBCAACEAACBCDAAEBACECEEBEDADCEEEBABCDDBEADDACAEECBAADBEDCBCDCDACCACBBBCDAEABBDBAEBDDBAAEBECCEADACADDDADCDDDCADCCEBBABEEECDEBEDDAEDEEAEDACAAAEBCBEEADDADCEDDBDADACCADBEECDEADAAEBAADEABEADAECAEEDDBBCADAEBBCCEAAEEECDDAAEBECABADBABDECEBCACCAEBADCCBBCACDBDDAAEDAEEAACDAABCCABCEBACDECBDADECCCEDDEDDDEBBCBBDDEDACCBCABBCDDAACDCCCAACEDABAECEACBCCDBCCCEAEEACACCDEAECBDBCDEAEBAADDEEDDCEACAECEBECDAEEBDEDCDCEDEABBEABBAAAABBEADDDCEADEDEBDECCBDBCDCACDBEEEDBDBBEEAADABCBAAECDEAACCCBDCCCCCCBCEBBEECBABACEDDCEADADADCBDEBEECDBDEDECBCCEAEAEDAABCCDACACCBBBEAABCECEDDEBAECDBBDCAAECEBEDCCCBAABCDAABBBABCACCBAAADDBDABAEACEABECCACBAEDCEDACAADADAEDEDCBBCCEDACAEEBBBAAADBEBBBECCBBEAABDDDABDEABEACBCEABDEEECECCCBCDEAAABAABDBABECDCCCBBCDCCEACBDCADACBBBABCBBDDAAEAEEDBACCEDEEEDBECBEACADDEACAADDDCBADEBDEDECDDDDEADCDCEBCABAEBBDEBDAAABBCABAEBAEDBBACBAABBBABEECEDAEDBCAACCABCDEEADCEECCBDABDAEBDEAABEABBACDEEABCAEDBBECDCDECACDCECDAADABEAEECBCBBBBBDAAEADBCBABADCDABDAEAABDCCDCEADADDEEABDCDAAEAACAEECDAEEBDBBDBEDDBBCEDADEBADDAEDBAADCADEAAADAACCBDABCDDBDEBEDACCBABABDBDDCDABBBACCADCBADCBCDDBEDDDDDBECDDBAEDCDEDEADEECEEAABDACDEDDECEBEABCDADDCBBBBCCBDBABCCDDCADDDDABABCCBADADEBDDCCBBCDBEAABDAEEEEADDEAECECDCECBBEECECDCDCBADCABEBABDCCACCEABCACDAABEBDBCDBBBCCEADAEACECDCAECAEEDAAADCEBEBCBBDCEEDBCABDDAEEBBBEDCBCEDABCEADCBCBECBACCABEEADADDBCACDBAEACCAEDDACEEAACADACEDDCAEADCABCDEEDADECDECDDDCDECACDECCBCDBDADEEDCDECEDBAEAEEECCACDCCADABEDAEDCCEBCBEBEAEADBABEDBACBDBBAABCCEEDEEBDABADADBDBEDDBBDDADCCEBECEDABABAAACCBDEACEBCDACBDCAEDDDDADCBEEECEEABDDAAEDDCABAABCDEECECCDCEDCACEDCEDDBDCDBADEDACDECADDDCCCDCDBABECEABDABBDDEEEDAACEBAEDBBEDBDBCDEABEBDDEEBDABDBDEACBDABCCADCCAEAAAECDBDEBAECAEECEACCBEECCEDAAEECBDBBBDCADCDCCABDDDEBBEDCCCADBDECEBDBBCDAEBEDEABDBBACCEDAACEEDEBBEDBEDBBECECDBCEABCDAEBDDEBADBEBBEDADCECAAACDAAEEBBDDEABEACBADBDAECDAADEBACEAADCAEDAEEEEECAACBCCEBCBAEEABCEDCBBAEABEEEAECECBEDABCCBABEECCEDADAEDBBCBBEEBDACACEEDBCEDDAEEEDBEDAADDCEDBEDCECCCAAAEBEBDACAEBAEAAABDEEBCBDDCCBBAACBBAEAADEECECCECDDBCCEEDAADADABECEDEDACADEAABADABCDDCECADEDEEACDAECDDEBDCBBADEDBDCDCBDABCCCBDEBECDBEAEDEADBDDDACDAACEEAEEACCDAEABCCADCBDACEBAEEEBAEBABBBEEBDBBBBAAACDEEBAACCBBDCDCDCDACCDEBDBAEDDDDBBDDDDAEEAEABCCECCEEBDCCBBBDBDDEACABEBAAEADDECACCBDEBADACCAAEADDDEACBEECBDDABBBDBEBBCAADDEACBCACEDDAEBBABBABAACEBBDEABCCCCEABEDCDEEADBDBCACABEADABCBDDDEEDDABBAACDAEBDDCBBACADCBBAAADBBAECBEEEDEEBDBCEBAAEDCCADBEACBAAECBDABABACACBBCDAADADDEEEABABEDDAAECAECBAEEECACDCDCDCEDAAECECDBCCAEEBDAACEBBDBAEADECBDEABBDCADCEBCAACADDCCAEBACBEAAABCDCDBCDCCBAECAEAEDBCAEDEEEBBDBDBACEDAEEEADABDABECEECACADEDEBCCCDBAAABBDABEEADDBECBDCADEEBADCADEAABDCAADCCAEBDDCCBCABEDDECADDBCECDACBAEBCDACEEADAEDBECEDBEDBBDABCADEBEBBBDBAEEBBDDAACEEBEDECAEECBBCEADDECEEBADADEEAAECACCAEDEBCCBBEBDDADBCDBEDDDBEBCEECADBDDBEDDEACAABEECECCAEECEEADEABACAEECAEBDCABBCBDBEDCCECECCAECECBDCEAEACDBBAADDDBBEDCEBCBBCBADAEDDEEDECEECBBDECBACBCCDEDDAEDCAEBBADDEDAAADCBDEAAADEBDDBADECDEADCCBCCDDCBBCECABBCBBABADACCEABCDAEDADCAACAACCAEBEDDEDBAEBDECCDDEEEACAAAECCBEDCECEDAABECEECDDAABEEAABCECEBEADAADDBCCDEEEDCBACAADCADEDACCBBCDABEBDABEACCBDDCEDBBCCEDAEBACDCCEACEBCAABCCDBAAEBBADCBAAEDECECBCCEBBEAEEABCBCADBEADECCABADDDCBBBECDCCDECEAEADABAEACAAABADBACCEBBBADDCBCECCACDCDCCEBBDDAEBCDBECDEEECBCCBDBDBBDADADDDAACCADDEBCDADEBCBCBCCADBDDEBEBAADDAABBCCCEBEBECCABEEAEECDEDEDAADBDAECACDACEDBBCACEDCEDECBADCCEDEDADBBACABCEDCDDCDDBDECADEEBCDCEEBBDEDDDBECBADCDBEACADEADDACDDAEDCEDEDCCBACCCEADACCBEBEDCDBDEDCCCCAEBEDCEABCCDAEEAAADBEABDDEADEBCCAADDCCDAAEDBADBDECDBBCECBECCDEEBDEECAEBDDABAAEEEEADEBDBBCDDCBBEEBDECEABAEBAEBBEAADDABBBAEEBEBAACBECDBCADECDABADACCCECAECABBACAAAEBEBAACACBEEAEAEDDACCCEADADECBDDECBECCDEDAADCEBABBDAACEEBBBAEDCDDDBDEEACAABCDEBEDBACEDACBBEEBCBBBDEEBDABABEBACEAADBCADABADDADACACADCAECEBDDCDDCCECDCBBEAAEBDDCBACEEBACBDABEBEDBDDABABEABADABABABAEABCEBCABBBBEEEDACCADCEBBEEAEBEEECCCBDBEDDBDCEEECBBBDCAEEBACEACCCDBEDBABACDCCABACDABDCDBEECAABBABCDBBDDBDCBCDEEDCBBACCBBBAAACCDAECBDDDDCABCCABDECCEAACABEECEBBEBCBBABCDECEAAAAECABCCAECCCDCDCBCCADABCADCECDECECDCBDBDBACBBAAEDCADAEDBEEDDEAEEDDBABAADEBDCEEECCCAEEEDACAECDBCACEDDDAECDEEDCEEBACCDCDCDBAAEDCABBBADDBCDEDDEEEDCDBCBCBCABABDBEDCBAABBEDCDEDBEEEEBDDAADCECBBACDAEAAEDBCEAACBAEDDEBEAADAECBECDDECAACBDBCCECBCCACBECBEAECADBBEEADEABABBBEDADBACCECDAAAACCBEAEDCDBEAABACDBACCACBBCCCBADBABBEDDACEEADBCCEBBAEEECBABEEBACACDABEAEEEEEAABACCBADDBCACCBCADDDABBAADBDAEECACEDBEADCEADADAECECDCADEDCBAADDDADBCCAEEEDCCAEBABADAACBACDEACECAACBAACEDEEDCBEBEDCAEBDAABACACAEBAEEEAEDEEABBACBBBABBBDBDCEAEBDDCECACAECABDDBCBBEDBDCEAABEAABDABBACBACDABABEBDEEEBADACBDBEBDECCABCEECAEAAEBDCEBDDECDEDBADBEDCDCBACBAADCBEADBEEEDDEEEABCEACADBDABBEAAEAEDADEABECAEEDEEEBCBDBDDBDDCAECCDBAAAEEEDDDAEDDEECCACBCADDDBBCBDCABEEEECDBEAADCCBAEAABACCCCEACDAAEACBDCEADCDEAADDACEBAAACAAACEBCDDBEEEADDADAADDDEEEBDCACEDCECBBACBBABEEEABCCBEEBDABDAEBDDEAABECDCABBDBADECACCACEEAAABACDDDBDBDCDEEEAEEDDAABDEECDEDCECACAADECCABBDECBECEBACDDCBACBEABBAEADCBACEECABABEDBEBBDECACABCEABCBEBEBBABEDCAADDCABDDEBBBBAEEEBEBBBBBACADCDAECEACABCDEDBAECDDCBEDAADBDCAAEDCCEDBECDACDBDDAEACECEBBCECDDDEBBBEABDAADCDCBEADBADACEBCCDCEBCEAABABEEDCCECCDECEDCDACCBBCEBDDECEEBABDAABDEDAADECABDEDAEAEDADDCBCCCAADBEBDCDBAADBBEBEDDCDDCDDDADBAB

Простите, что не могу перенести в виде файла .txt, так как это не позволяет сайт.

Answer (score 2):

Делайте по шагам:

```
if a[i]=='B' or a[i]=='C' or a[i]=='D': 
    if a[i+1]=='B' or a[i+1]=='D' or a[i+1]=='E':
        if a[i+1]) != a[i]:
             if a[i+2]=='B' or a[i+2]=='C' or a[i+2]=='E':
                  if a[i+2] != a[i + 1]:
                      total += 1
```